# how to access to a remote MySQL database from a nodejs app inside a kubernetes pod?

Tags: mysql, node.js, kubernetes

I have created a POD that contains a nodejs app from which I'm trying to connect to a remote database in another server. My POD configuration goes like this:

```
apiVersion : "v1"
kind : "Service"
metadata :
  name : "mysql"
spec :
  ports :
    -
      name : "mysql"
      protocol : "TCP"
      port : 3306
      targetPort : 3306
      nodePort : 0
---
kind: "Endpoints"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "mysql"
subsets:
  -
    addresses:
      -
        ip: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" #The IP Address of the external web server
    ports:
      -
        port: 3306
        name: "mysql"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: productos
  labels:
    app: productos
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: productos
      tier: backend
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: productos
        tier: backend
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - image: sospinah/tutorial:lopido-ms-productos6
        name: productos
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_HOST
          value: "mysql.default.svc.cluster.local"
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: "<username>"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: "<dbname>"
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: "<password>"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
```

In my nodejs application I have defined my database connection as follows:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
});
```

And I'm getting a timeout error on app startup

```
> nodejs-microservice@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node index.js

server listening at port 0.0.0.0:4000
error connecting mysql:  { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:419:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:422:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.bdConfig.testConection (/usr/src/app/database/config.js:16:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/index.js:18:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

I would like to know what am I missing in my POD configuration and/or application configuration.

Comment: I'm guessing you found a solution to this problem. I have the exact issue. Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

you have defined mysql host as mysql.default.svc.cluster.local

This would work if both nodejs and mysql run in same kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I still can not connect my pod with a database hosted on another server.

Comment: where is the database running? on vm or in a pod?

Comment: the database is in a MV

Answer (score 1):

You can use service name to connect pods internally. you can use 'mysql' service name if your webserver is running inside same kubernetes cluster.

If you want to run your mysql inside kubernetes cluster and want to make connection outside of kubenetes cluster then probably you can expose your mysql service to internet and you can to your mysql database from anywhere. If your all application running inside same cluster then use a service name to resolve the address.

Comment: Can you please explain how to connect the pod to a database that is on external server. Thank you so much

Comment: if your database is running on external server you can simple use the IP address and credentials in your code.

Comment: if your node application running inside the POD they specify that IP addresss as host and username password in node code.

Comment: Yes of course I'm passing the credentials of the database but I still rejects the connection. the database and the kubernetes cluster is located on a private LAN I believe that the conflict is generated because the host ip with which nodejs rises is removed from the LAN?

Comment: May possible also you are sure about the firewall from database side ? port is open and database is public ?

Comment: The basis of the data is not alone.

Comment: database running on ?

Comment: Database runs on? do you mean the engine or the server (MV)?

Comment: server is it vm or pod ?

Comment: at place of : MYSQL_HOST you have to add respective IP and also add value in ther variables. it should have to work if there is no network and firewall issue.

Comment: the database is in an MV

Comment: MV didn't get that  ? MV mean ?

Comment: sorry, it's virtual machine

Comment: VM is running on ? aws GCP digital ocean ?

Comment: check for port or firewall having open access to internet.

Comment: There is no possibility of doing a Kind: Endpoint or Kind: Service that allows me to link my pod with the server of the bd.

if I raise a server with node js inside my pod where the localhost set the IP of the Pod generated by the K8s this can be an inconvenience to connect my mysql?

Comment: kind:service is way to expose your application either internally or externally with kind:service you can not make connection to database running outside.